# Laravel 5, how to if a Checkbox is checked in the controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

in my view

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.users.save', $entry->id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Kaydet
        </button>
    </div>


    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="hidden" name="is_it_admin" value="0">
            <input type="checkbox" name="is_it_admin" value="1" {{ old('is_it_admin', $entry->is_it_admin) ? 'checked' : '' }}> Aktif Mi
        </label>
    </div>

</form>
```

this is my form in the view

this İn my controller save function

```
public function save($id = 0){

   $data = \request()->only('name_surname','email');


    $data['is_it_admin'] = \request()->has('is_it_admin') ? 1 : 0;
    if ($id>0){
        $entry = User::where('id',$id)->firstOrFail();
        $entry->update($data);
    }
    else{

        $entry = User::create($data);
    }

    return redirect()
        ->route('admin.users.edit',$entry->id);

}
```

It doesn't work when I use 'has' but  it works when you don't use 'has' . Why

Comment: Your template field is named `is_it_active` while you check `is_it_admin` in your controller. Typo or wrong in the code?

Comment: Also input tag is not closed ? `>`

Comment: I didn't put the entire block of teacher code. no wrong I wanted to check both admin and activity.

I have edited

Comment: checkbox always returns true dd(\request()->has('is_it_admin'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request()->has()` returns a boolean indicating if the field is present or not. That's not what you want since your field will be always present (even if value is 0)

What you need is `request()->get()`:

```
public function save($id = 0){

   $data = \request()->only('name_surname','email');


    $data['is_it_admin'] = \request()->get('is_it_admin');
    if ($id>0){
        $entry = User::where('id',$id)->firstOrFail();
        $entry->update($data);
    }
    else{

        $entry = User::create($data);
    }

    return redirect()
        ->route('admin.users.edit',$entry->id);

}
```

Although, you don't need to do this, you can just:

```
public function save($id = 0){

   $data = \request()->only('name_surname','email', 'is_it_admin');

    if ($id > 0){
        $entry = User::where('id',$id)->firstOrFail();
        $entry->update($data);
    }
    else {
        $entry = User::create($data);
    }

    return redirect()
        ->route('admin.users.edit',$entry->id);

}
```

Comment: worked in both methods you said thank you. very thank you

Comment: If it helped you, pleas mark the answer as correct and upvote it! Thanks!